# Stop application restart on class file change in Eclipse WTP with Tomcat and Serve modules without publishing enabled

Tags: tomcat, eclipse-wtp

It seems to be impossible to prevent application from reloading on a class file change when "*Serve modules without publishing*" is enabled. I have "*Never publish automatically*" selected in Server configuration, but every time I modify a class file (not a JSP - with JSP changes all is OK), my web app gets restarted.

After some digging around I found that changing `<Context .. reloadable="true"` to `false` in `server.xml` stops the reloading.

But how do I tell WTP to publish applications with `reloadable` set to `false`? It seems to be always publishing with `reloadable="true"`, regardless of my publishing preferences...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Going to answer my own question. Just go to the Servers view, double-click on the server, select Modules tab at the bottom, and disable auto-reloading there. Done.

Comment: Thanks for that.  What's the best way to trigger a publish after that?

Comment: Right-click on server, select "Publish". But the servlets will never be reloaded I think, the only way to reload is to restart Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same issue while using Tomcat in Eclipse. My Tomcat server was ON when Eclipse get closed forcefully , when I open again and start Error: *"Port is running"* .

To fix this, kill this port process using command. 
And next time, in your server do *-> Open configuration -> Argument-> Stop start -> Apply*

So whenever your Eclipse exits or gets terminated, the server automatically stops.